# PHP file redirect to given link

Tags: php

I have search on the web, yet I can't get the answer where a single PHP file could redirect to given url.

Like example I see on the website when I click the contact link on the menu I can see the url like below. And it redirect me to contact page. Even when I try placed other domain on the redirect 'to' location it can work as usual.

What is the best way to have a single file where could work like this

example.com/redir?s=icon_topost&url=http://www.example.com/contact (redir)

or

mydomain.com/redir.php?=http//www.mydomain.com/contact (redir.php)

I have try this code. I can't.

```
<?php header('Location: http://'); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: http:// is not a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, but you must have not returned anything in the body to be able to change headers. What's the error PHP is displaying?

`<?php header("Location: $_GET['url']"); ?>`